# Access token is used against invalid domain

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito

I have implemented the following code in my plain JavaScript webpage:

```js
const http = new XMLHttpRequest()

http.open("GET", "<CognitoPoolDomainName>.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo");
http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
http.send();

http.onload = () => console.log(http.responseText);
});
```

the jwt token can be decrypt well in https://jwt.io/.

But I am getting this error message:

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Access token is used against invalid domain"}
```

Can you help me tin understand what token - in which format - is required by this API Endpoint?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have an `aud` claim in the token? Usually, this is the claim which tells receivers for which domain/API is the token intended. Also

Comment: yes, I have an aud but this doesn't look like a domain. It says "Webmessaging" which is the purpose if the endpoint I am dealing with. But no domain. Do I need to setup anything in Cognito to map a domain name and the aud?